Meta-feature analysis: Intermediate results to assess complexity among different feature combinations
I'm using the meta-feature analysis package. It provides a convenient way to summary meta-features statistics.
However in this case, I am looking for a way to access "intermediate" results for complexity analysis of data points in data set through pairwise feature combination. This is to enable me understand with features leads to high class overlap (complexity) than others.
For example, in iris dataset with just 4 features (sepal-length, sepal-width, petal-length, petal-width ):
pip install -U pymfe # package install

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from pymfe.mfe import MFE
data = load_iris()
X= data.data
y = data.target

Instead of overall summary:
extractor = MFE(features=[ "f1"], groups=["complexity"],
                  summary=["mean", "sd"])
extractor.fit(X,y)
meta_feat = extractor.extract()

to get the mean and std-dev, I would like to analyse the complexity due to sepal-length v sepal-width, sepal-length v petal-length, sepal-length v petal-width, etc... Since f1 projects data points along vertical axes for combination of binary features.
What is the way to achieve this?
If possible, some visualisation help will be appreciated as well.
